# Selecting deployment configuration based on branch

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

At the moment I have a working Jenkins declarative pipeline set up as a paramterized build, and a git pre-push hook set up to build it.

I would like to migrate to a multi-branch setup, where the `feature/<someCoolFeature>` and `development` branches are configured to deploy to one server, `test` is configured to deploy to a different server and `production` to the production server.

I am comfortable with triggering builds and defining parameters for which branches are built when, but all the documentation, questions and blog posts skip over a central thing:

***How do I configure the deployment variables for the different servers?***

As I see it, since you don't have `switch` and `if` control structures in declarative pipelines. I have to create a library which looks up which `BRANCH_NAME` I am building, and set the environment variables, or choose the corresponding `application-<env>.yml` based on that, but there must be a best practice somewhere that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Though not encouraged for the sake of simplicity and purpose of the declarative pipelines, you can still use both `switch` and `if` control structures within them:

Before the `pipeline {...}` block

```
// switch or if statements here

pipeline {
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside a stage by wrapping them within a `script {}` block:

```
stage('prepare-env') {
    steps {
        script {
            // switch or if statements here
        }
    }
}
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script.

Comment: For future reference the `switch` has to be contained in a `node`  group